# Check if iframe is inside of text

Tags: html, ruby, regex

```
p.content
 => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras gravida quis orci sed pellentesque. Nam ullamcorper. Proin eget dapibus tellus. <br /><br /><iframe title=\"title\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/yt_video_id\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"\"></iframe>"
```

I would like to know if is possible check if inside of `p.content` text exist or not a youtube iframe.

Comment: why not use a regexp to check for `/iframe/` followed by `/src=.+youtube/`

Comment: I [wouldn't do it with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2936460)...

Comment: hmm, how about a constructive comment instead of just saying, what you would NOT do?

Comment: Can anyone answer with an example? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't so many choises, I think; you have to parse the string and check if the parsed object is what you expect, for example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

fragment = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(p.content)
fragment.css('iframe[src*="www.youtube.com"]').any?
# => true

fragment.css('iframe[src*="www.google.com"]').any?
# => false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a string has a substring containing some text using the `include?` method:

```
p.content.include? "iframe"
```

Here are the docs for `include?`, http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know if is a youtube iframe!